# Order of growth for given functions

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I've tried to sort these functions in asymptotic growth order and would like to know if I'm on the right track.

[image: List of what I have to sort]

1. 5000log2(n)
2. sqrt(n) +7
3. 8n
4. n/log2(n)
5. 4nlog2(n)
6. n^1/100
7. 1/4 n^2 - 10000n
   .

Comment: Have you thought of a programming framework you'd like to test these out on? The simplest thing to do would be to produce plots of the 7 functions, and eyeball check to see which is growing the fastest - though there are better methods depending on your language of choice.

Comment: This is not a homework-based site. You can try an plot these functions into Excel and see what their growth is like.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The above list would be -
1) 5000log2(n)
2) n^(1/100)
3)sqrt(n)+7
4)n/log2(n)
5)8n
6)4nlog2(n)
7)1/4n^2-10000n

as per my knowledge.
For more information on the topic you can see the definition of O(n),Big-theta n  and Omega - n

Correction to the above list are most welcomed

Answer (score 1):

You can test if `f(n)` is asymptotically larger than `g(n)` by checking if

```
lim  f(n) / g(n) = ∞
n->∞
```

If the limit is a non-zero constant, `f(n)` and `g(n)` are asymptotically equal. If it is zero, `f(n)` is asymptotically smaller than `g(n)`.

So. The major part of your list looks correct. There are a few mistakes, though.

`n/log2(n)` should be between `sqrt(n) + 7` and `8n`.

`n^(1/100)` is the 100-th root of `n` and should be before the square-root.